# Javascript not loaded completely

Tags: javascript, websphere, rad

I am facing issue while running my Application in Local environment. The Javascript errors start popping when I login to application. Getting errors like..

> 1. Message: Unterminated string constant
>      Line: 2374
>      Char: 46
>      Code: 0
> 2. Message: Expected '}'
>      Line: 2373
>      Char: 1

In Actual file the function starts at 2372 which is :

```
function isAlphaNumericWithDash(checkStrValue) {  
  var checkOK = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab"; 
  //cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-
  var checkStr = checkStrValue;     
  //Some more lines 
}
```

But in Actual loaded file the file is ending at line  2374, the code lines are  :

```
function isAlphaNumericWithDash(checkStrValue) {
  var checkOK = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab"
```

Similar error getting in every flow. When I refresh the screen, sometimes screen start appearing, but not functioning properly.

When I am checking the js files, found that these files are not loaded completely.

Wondering what can be the reason.

Info :

RAD Version : 
Version: 8.0.4.2 iFix1
Build ID: RADO8042iFix1-I20130214_1904

Server : 
WebSphere Application Server v8.0 at localhost

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise
64 bit operating system
Model : win7 *64 1.7
RAM: 4 GB

Lines in incomplete loaded file : 2374
Size of incomplete loaded file: 64.0 KB (65,536 bytes)

Lines in complete file : 4456
Size of Complete file : 124 KB (126,976 bytes

** The same Application is working in other machines except few machine configured for one new team.
** This is not browser related issue, as testing and Production environment url are working perfectly in same browsers(IE 8, 9, Chrome, Mozzila etc.).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show us the lines 2374 and 2373.

Comment: In Actual file the function starts at 2372 which is : function isAlphaNumericWithDash(checkStrValue)
{
 var checkOK = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab"; //cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-
 var checkStr = checkStrValue;
 //Some more lines
}     But in Actual loaded file the file is ending at line  2374, the code lines are  : function isAlphaNumericWithDash(checkStrValue)
{
 var checkOK = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab"

Comment: How are you loading js files? Are they included in the <head> or via link? Are they plain js files or jsp files containing javascript? Looks like you might be hitting some 64k limit somewhere.

Comment: These are plain js file is included in <head> tag in Jsp Page. The Jsp also consists of some java script, but issue is coming in loading the external js file in bigger size. Please let me know what is this 64k limit, where it is set and can it be increased. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Also same file are working fine on other machines.

Comment: @kool_developer - Are the other machines same OS, same WAS version? Whats the differnce? How script it is included in <head> (add example to your question)? (You need to add `@user` to notify about your comment).

Comment: @Gas Other machines are of exact same configuration, same OS, same RAD and Server, Same Code deployed taken from svn. The only difference were difference in the intranet setting earlier , which were <on my machine it was custom, but on other machines it were Medium-low. Which on request, our IT team made these setting same on my machine too, even after facing the same issue.(I restarted the system, application, cleared the cache etc.)

Comment: @Gas Script included in head like this                         <script src="/myApp/js/appValidation.js?ver=v7.11"></script>

Comment: If it works on same RAD and WAS, then it must be something on your machine (maybe firewall?), sorry cant help you in that.